# Controling the size of components in Swing when their frame is resized

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a simple form like this:

Username: ..........

Password: ..........

When the form is re-sized, I would expect `JTextField` (illustrated by .........) to be re-sized horizontally to fit the new width but not vertically (the same height for `JTextField`). Do we have any way to control this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your layout with the standard layout managers (except GridBag), nest layouts as follows:

```
BorderLayout
    NORTH=BorderLayout   // keep everything at the top
        WEST=GridLayout(0,1) // the labels
            Label "UserName")
            Label "Password")
        CENTER=GridLayout(0,1) // the fields
            Text Field
            Password Field
```

Code would look something like

```
JPanel outer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,3,3));
JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,3,3));
outer.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
top.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
top.add(fields, BorderLayout.CENTER);
labels.add(new JLabel("Username"));
labels.add(new JLabel("Password"));
fields.add(new JTextField());
fields.add(new JPasswordField());
```

See http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/GUI/AWTLayoutMgr/ for my (very old) explanation of how to nest layout managers like this.

GridBag is evil incarnate; just about impossible to figure out what the code is doing if you have more than a few components. To show how this would be done, though:

```
Insets i = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
p.add(new JLabel("Username"), 
  new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, i, 0, 0));
p.add(new JLabel("Password"), 
  new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, i, 0, 0));
p.add(new JTextField(), 
  new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, i, 0, 0));
p.add(new JPasswordField(), 
  new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, i, 0, 0));
```

It works, but it's hard to "see" the layout in the code...

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the layout manager you have used.

The default layout ([`FlowLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html))will not resize the components at all.

If you want fine grained control over how your components resize, look into [`GridBagLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).

The easy way out though, is to use [`setResizable(false)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable(boolean)).
For something as simple as a login window, that is probably the way you want to go.

If you are interested in using different layouts, you may want to look into the Java Tutorials.  They have a great [section on laying out components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: btw: FlowLayout is the default for (j)panels; BorderLayout is the default for (j)frames

Comment: sorry - one more. do not use setResizable(false). different platforms or L&Fs may use different default fonts, different locales, etc, which may cause the layout to resize. using setResizable(false) may end up cutting off some components if they resize due to fonts/text.

Comment: If you make sure to call pack(), the GUI will resize to a good size, then you use steResizable() to make sure it stays that size.

Comment: pack() may help, but it tends to leave things a little tight. I understand why you're suggesting it (layout managers definitely aren't trivial), but it makes for a less friendly UI. My name being somewhat long, I like to resize dialogs so I can see it all at once

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to control it with one layout manager (for any usage) would be using **[MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)**

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

panel.add(firstNameLabel);
panel.add(firstNameTextField);
panel.add(lastNameLabel,       "gap unrelated");
panel.add(lastNameTextField,   "wrap");
panel.add(addressLabel);
panel.add(addressTextField,    "span, grow");
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [miglayout.com](http://www.miglayout.com/images/Form.png))</sub>

Comment: 3rd party layout managers feel like cheating.  But that manager looks really cool.

Comment: @jjnguy; I agree ;) I only use this one now: it replaces all the others.